# Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/internal/ClientApi;

Tags: unity-game-engine, exception

I am getting this error

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe -classpath "G:\Program_Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.2.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformDexWithDexForRelease'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/internal/ClientApi;
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
]

please help me....

Comment: Are you building your Unity game with Android plugin?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Android platform for building purpose.

Comment: Sorry, I mean do you put any files with `aar` or `jar` extension into `Assets/Plugins/Android` folder in your project? Or do you import some Google packages into your project?

Comment: Thanks for your concern. But the problem is solved now .

Comment: You are welcome. You can post a solution to explain what the problem was and how you solved it. Maybe someone will have the same problem in the future.

Comment: First i create a backup file and delete all the lastly imported packages (In my case Firebase, Google Play Services, Admob etc) and Re-import them all (Assets -> Re-import All). Then I click on (Play Services Resolver>Android Resolver>Force Resolve) to reslove the dependencies. After that, the error was gone but the app were crashing repeatedly again and again (during build and run). So finally, I just copy and paste the AndroidManifest.xml in the Plugins>Android Directory folder which Which I accidentally deleted while deleting packages. Now my Project is working perfectly.